# Merge key values in a multidimensional array php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'd like to merge duplicated array values based on the `author_id` into one. My code is as follows:

```
 public function full_array( $date_query, $minimum ) {          
    $data = $this->date_array_freqency( $date_query, $minimum );
    $products = array();

    foreach( $data as $id => $sales ) {
        $products[] = array (
            'author_id'     => get_post_field( 'post_author', $id ),
            'product_id'    => $id,
            'sales'         => $sales                   
          );
    }           
}
```

Multi-dimensional array looks like this:

```
Array
(
    ....

    [4] => Array
        (
            [author_id] => 27
            [product_id] => 166
            [sales] => 6
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [author_id] => 25
            [product_id] => 1056
            [sales] => 6
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [author_id] => 27
            [product_id] => 331
            [sales] => 6
        )

)
```

When there's an identical author id, I'd like to combine the array into something like this:

```
[4] => Array
        (
            [author_id] => 27
            [product_id] => array( 166, 331)
            [sales] => array(6, 6)
        )
```

Any guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: Do you need to keep the original numeric array key? If not, I would use the author_id as key, then you can easily “look up” whether an entry for an id already exists in your `$products` array using `isset`. Otherwise you will have to search the array for an entry with that author_id first. (It might make sense to have the product_id and sales be arrays in any case, so for your second item with author_id 25 that would then be `[product_id] => array(331)` and `[sales] => array(6)` - usually easier to work with such data if the format is consistent.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the `for-loop` in `full_array` function to do something like that:

```
foreach( $data as $id => $sales ) {
    $aId = get_post_field( 'post_author', $id );
    if (isset($products[$aId])) { // if the author already in the result just add the data
        $products[$aId]["product_id"][] = $id;
        $products[$aId]["sales"][] = $sales;

    } else { // if not exist add new data 
        $products[$aId] = array('author_id' => $aId, 'product_id' => [$id], 'sales' => [$sales]);
    }
}
```

If you don't want the keys (author ID) in the result array just use [array-values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php)

Comment: This is a better answer than mine. Didn't notice the code created the array.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!